# Umbraco 7.2 not reconnecting to SQL Azure when a failed connection occurs

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, umbraco7

I've got an Umbraco 7.2 site that is running on windows azure using SQL Azure as the database.  At least once a week, SQL Azure is reporting a failed connection and Umbraco doesn't automatically reconnect.  All users receive a 500 error when visiting the site.  This is a huge issue and I'm unsure how to resolve it.

When any of the failed connections occur, the site goes down for everyone. Any help would or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Does your application code handle transient error such as DB connection transient errors?

Comment: As the most common thing, have you enabled firewall settings, so that your application can talk to Azure SQL Server?

Comment: The application works 99% of the time and connects to the database just fine. I did not create Umbraco so I'll just assume they are handling transient db connection errors.

Comment: Umbraco puts error logs in app_data somewhere, right? I would start there and see what kind of errors you were getting at the time of these failed connections. Add them to your question here if they don't make sense, but I'm betting you will see a pretty obvious error there.

Comment: To Clarify, the log location is App_Data/Logs

Comment: I only get SqlException's stating that the database is unavailable.  If I restart the Azure website then everything returns back to normal.  It's as if Umbraco is caching the 500 error and unable to "snap out of it and reconnect when the database is ok again.  I think the SQL Azure database is recycling or something and when this happens, it generates a SqlException in Umbraco.

There are no other web application errors worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

I've run several Umbraco sites on Azure Websites with Azure SQL and don't have this issue. I did recently have a problem with an Umbraco 7.2 site when SQL Azure went down for a few hours and had to restart the web server after that.

I think this will be fixed by upgrading to Umbraco 7.3 or newer per this issue: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6597